# How to create a 2-dimensional array from two 1-dimensional ones in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that I want to combine into one 2-dimensional array.

```
$firstnames = array("Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty");

$lastnames = array("Brown", "Smith", "Hughes", "Malone");
```

I want an array `$bothnames['firstname']['lastname']`, which I would like to echo and use to check against a PID field later on.

I've tried everything I know to populate the 2-dimensional array and echo it.

```
// populate

$bothnames = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($firstnames); $i++)
 { 
    $bothnames[$i] = array();
        for ($x=0; $x<count($lastnames); $x++)
        {
           $bothnames[$i][$x] = $lastnames[$x];
        }
 }


// echo

for ($i=0; $i<count($firstnames); $i++)
 { 
   for ($x=0; $x<count($lastnames); $x++)
    {
    echo $bothnames[$i][$x]; 
    echo "<br>";
    }

  }
```

This just gives the last names (and loops 4 times). How can I get the output

```
Jim Brown
Jack Smith
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the arrays using the following method:

```
<?php
$firstnames = array("Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty");
$lastnames = array("Brown", "Smith", "Hughes", "Malone");
$names = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($firstnames as $fn)
{
    $names[$fn] = $lastnames[$i];
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($names);
```

Using these later:

```
foreach($names as $first => $last)
{
    $firstName = $first;
    $lastName = $last;
}
```

It is to be noted that the length of both arrays should be same.

Comment: Thank you! That's great, but can I index the first names and last names separately with $names[][] notation somehow? I'll need to in a later SQL query; they're separate DB fields.

Comment: Yes you can let me update the code for you using the foreach loop you can separately get the first and last name..

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had!  Done now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_combine function

```
$firstnames = array("Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty");
$lastnames = array("Brown", "Smith", "Hughes", "Malone");
$bothnames = array_combine($firstnames, $lastnames);

foreach($bothnames as $key=>$value){
    echo $key." ".$value;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to utilize the power of PHP arrays. Here's an example:

```
$firstnames = array("Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty");
$lastnames = array("Brown", "Smith", "Hughes", "Malone");
$bothnames = array_map(function ($firstname, $lastname) {
       return [$firstname,$lastname];
}, $firstnames, $lastnames);

foreach ($bothnames as $fullname) {
     echo $fullname[0]." ".$fullname[1];
}
```

Prints:

> Jim Brown
>
> Jack Smith
>
> Mary Hughes
>
> Betty Malone

[array_map details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Thanks for the link as well. Useful function! I added  ."<br />"; to print as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_combine if you are sure that array has equal length

```
$firstnames = ["Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty"];
$lastnames = ["Brown", "Smith", "Hughes"];
$bothnames = array_combine($firstnames, $lastnames);

foreach ($bothnames as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " " . $value;
    echo "\n";
}
```

or if you are not sure this code is more safe

```
$firstnames = ["Jim", "Jack", "Mary", "Betty"];
$lastnames = ["Brown", "Smith", "Hughes", "Malone"];

foreach ($firstnames as $k => $v) {
    echo $v . (isset($lastnames[$k]) ? ' ' . $lastnames[$k] : '');
    echo "\n";
}
```